# Como puedo hacer para que devuelva un mensaje si la busqueda no coincide con ningun producto de la base de datos

Tags: php, base-de-datos

El codigo devuelve el h1 vacio si el usuario busca, por ejemplo, "asdasdasd".
Lo que estoy buscando es que si el usuario busca algo que no esté relacionado con ningun producto de la base de datos tambien me devuelva este mensaje.

```
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['busqueda'])){
                $busqueda = $_GET['busqueda'];
            }

            $consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
            if($busqueda != ''){
                while($mostrar = $consulta->fetch_array()){
                    echo $mostrar['nombre'];
                }
            }else{
                echo '<h1>No se encontró ningún producto, marca o kit con este nombre.</h1>';
                // Muestra este mensaje si la busqueda esta vacia
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: No se entiende cual es el problema, amplia tu código o agrega un ejemplo. Observando tus **if** de comprobación, no están empleados correctamente si es que no te arroja ningún resultado.

Answer (score 0):

En ningún momento estas verificando la respuesta de tu consulta de bbdd.

Si estas usando mysqli ,puedes utilizar la propiedad de num_rows para validar la edvolucion.

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['busqueda'])){
            $busqueda = $_GET['busqueda'];
        }

        $consulta = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
        if($consulta->num_rows > 0){
            while($mostrar = $consulta->fetch_array()){
                echo $mostrar['nombre'];
            }
        }else{
            echo '<h1>No se encontró ningún producto, marca o kit con este nombre.</h1>';
            // Muestra este mensaje si la busqueda esta vacia
        }
    ?>
```